# What rule is used to go from $(27\times 28/2) + 28$ to $28 \times (27/2 + 1)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There's a calculation in my math book that goes from $(27\times 28/2) + 28$ to $28 \times (27/2 + 1).$ I don't understand how they went from the first to the second step. How did they switch the $+ 28$ to the $\times 28$?

Can someone intuitively explain this to me with the rules behind it?

Comment: The rule is called the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) i.e $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

We have $27\times\frac{28}{2} + 28 $

- Isolate $28 \implies 27\times\frac{28}{2} + 28=28(27\times \frac{1}{2} +1) = 28(\frac{27}{2}+1)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{27*28}{2}+28=\frac{27*28}{2}+\frac{28}{1}=\frac{27*28}{2}+\frac{28}{1}\cdot\frac{2}{2}$$ $$=\frac{27*28}{2}+\frac{2*28}{2}=28\left(\frac{27}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\right)=28\left(\frac{27}{2}+1\right)$$

The last three steps result from factoring $28$ from both fractions.